# How to lock whole ManyToOne relation in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm

Assume that there is entity `Product`. Relation is set as follows:

`Product --1:N--> ImageLink <--N:1-- Image`

Such a setup is used to allow adding more info to the relation - who linked the image, when, etc. One of the attributes of `ImageLink` is also `isMainImage` (bool). That denotes that this one particular `ImageLink` contains the image we want to show as main image of the product.

When I want to set main image of the product I need to set all the ImageLinks to false except for the one I want to set as main. I retrieve the links from `Product` - `$product->getImageLinks()`. That will fetch all the `ImageLinks` entries from DB and convert them to objects. I will traverse over all of them and set the correct value for `isMainImage`. Then I flush the entity manager.

Someone could have added a new image and marked it as main image in the meantime.  That image was not selected from DB and was not converted to object. So is was not set to false. It will therefore not be changed during the flush.

**Now I have two main images. How do I solve this?**

Without ORM I would update the images in one db query, something like `UPDATE image_link SET is_main = IF(id = 13, 1, 0)`.

Comment: You are more then welcome to suggest better title. I had trouble describing the problem in one sentence :(